# Related Products Trick: A -> B && B -> A

Tags: product, catalog, products-management

Let's say I have 100 products.

Product Number 6 has 15 related products.

These 16 products (15 plus Product Number 6) should all be **related to each other**.

Is there a method or extension that allows me to have the selected products automatically related to each other?

I asked [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5590/magento-related-products-relating-all-products-to-each-other) and don't really understand if this can be done with my scenario.

Comment: What is special about those 15/16 products? If they were in a category together couldn't you just display products from the same category?

Comment: My company sells oriental carpets.  It would be nice to have, for example, 4' x 6' Hamadan carpets related to each other.  5' x 7' Hamadan carpets related to each other.  4' x 6' Tabriz carpets.  8' x 10' Kashans.  The category they fall under is traditional.  I could, of course, create a hidden category for each of these, however, that would be also be quite a lot of work.  I did find an extension that seems to be able to create rules to relate products, but I have not yet got it working to post it as an answer.

Comment: The way we handle this in large catalogs is to use categorization (as you put it, 'hidden' categories) and then let Magento display products from those categories. If you're using Magento Enterprise (I'm guessing you're not) this is a built-in feature. There are also plugins on Connect as you already know.

Comment: Let's say that I have all my products correctly in these 'hidden' categories like you have it set up.  Each hidden category has products that are related to each other product in that category. Do you have to go to each product and add that categories' contents as related products?  What if a new product gets added?

Comment: Or does the built in feature auto-update the newly added products?

Comment: In theory if a product is in the same 4x7 category as another product, it *is* related to it - they're in the same category, right? That's what Magento uses as one of the parameters to display those related products.

Comment: When adding a new product to Magento you would merchandise it into the proper category.

Comment: But, when adding a product, under the related products section, there is no way to say "Include this entire category as related products." You can sort by many things, but category is not one of them.  And even if you could, you would then have to update all other products once a new category is added.  However, this may not be an issue with Enterprise Edition. I do appreciate your help though.  I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: I believe what he's trying to say is not to use the related products section in the product update grid.  Instead, rely on the hidden category to determine what products to show in the related products block on your product view page. (Correct me if I'm wrong).  This way a product will show up on all other products' related products block as soon as you add it to that category.

Comment: Yes, I believe I understand that part. My question is, how do you get a category to show under the related products block?

Answer (score 1):

**Magento Enterprise** allows you to create dynamic rules for relations between products. If you are using community edition, keep in mind performance issues. 
Advices to use categories to show related products are right.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old, but in the meantime I developed [a FREE extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/ProductRelationsImport) that allows you to manage product relations easier.
It does not work exactly how you need it, by relating the products 2 ways when setting a relation in the backend, but it allows you to specify manually or through an import a list of product ids or skus that should be related among themselves.